# Multiple Keyword Search

Tags: php, mysql

I have a string containing comma separated keywords. For Example:

```
$location="Delhi,NOIDA";
$skill="PHP, PHP Programmer";
$cheack2 = "";
$arr=array();
$flag = false;
if(isset($skill) && $skill != "") {

    $query_arr = explode(",", $skill);

    foreach($query_arr as $query_arr2) {
        $arr[] = "job_keyskills like '%$query_arr2%' ";
    }

    $cheack2=implode(" OR ", $arr);
    $flag = true;
}
```

```
select * from tb_job where 1=1 and job_keyskills like '%PHP%' OR job_keyskills like '%PHP  Programmer%' OR job_location like '%Delhi%' OR job_location like '%Chhattisgarh%'
```

But I want this type of query

```
select * from tb_job where 1=1 and job_keyskills like '%PHP%' OR job_keyskills like '%PHP Developer%' AND job_location like '%Delhi%' OR job_location like '%NOIDA%'
```

Comment: Sorry, what is your question?

Comment: I tried to format your question to find the actual question, only to find out your code is not even valid.

Comment: Syntax error: `if($flag) { $cheack2 .= "OR ";` <-- Missing closing curly brace...

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your code:

```
if(isset($skill) && $skill != "") {
    if($flag) {
        $cheack2 .= "OR ";
    }
}
```

And you are missing braces:

```
select * from tb_job where 1=1 and (job_keyskills like '%PHP%' OR job_keyskills like '%PHP Developer%') AND (job_location like '%Delhi%' OR job_location like '%NOIDA%)
```

Comment: plz check my code am not using AND operator i want to add this in my code. I want to use both operato AND OR.